# How to find the center of black objects in an image with python opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a problem finding the contours of black objects on white background.

[image: example]

here I added an example of an image. 
Now I need to find center of black regions and I use following code.

```
im = cv2.imread(img)
plt.imshow(im)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
```

However it gives an error like

> **TypeError: Expected Ptr for argument 'image'** " for the image argument of *cv2.findeContours()*.

How can I solve this? or if you have any other idea how to find center of black regions I would like to hear. Thanks.

Comment: Use `thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]`, cf. the return values of [`threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57).

Comment: Sorry, It is fist time for me using Opencv, what do you mean cf. the return  values of threshold ?

Comment: But you do know, what [return statements](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/) are in general? When calling `cv2.threshold(...)` and forwarding the result(s) to a single variable `thresh`, that'll be a tuple consisting of `retval` and `dst`. When calling `cv2.threshold(...)[1]`, you only get `dst`, thus forwarding to `thresh`, your `thresh` is the actual thresholded image.

Comment: Thanks I understood what you mean , it kinda solved error related to threshold thanks for that. but there is new error for cv2.findContours() " error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:197: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl' " as I understood I should change the mode for image right ?

Comment: So, what's the type of your original image `img` (and following `gray`, `blurred`, and `thresh`), i.e. what's the output of `print(img.dtype)`? If it's anything other than `uint8`, you need to convert your image appropriately to use `cv2.findContours(...)` as intended.

Comment: I checked all of the are unit8, should I change smth else ?

Comment: Your original image is a three-channel image, thus `thresh` is three-channel also, which is not supported in `cv2.findContours(...)`. Use `thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, ...)` instead of `thresh = cv2.threshold(im, ...)` for example. (Haven't noticed that before...)

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem. I have one more question that I want to get coordinates. how Can I get coordinates of each contour ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. When you perform [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) on your image, OpenCV expects that the *foreground objects to detect are in white with the background in black.* To do this, you can [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) with the `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` parameter to get the objects in white. From here we can find contours and find the center of each region by calculating for the [centroid](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) with `cv2.moments`. Here's the results:

Binary image

[image]

Center of object drawn in blue with the bounding box in green. You can get the coordinates of each contour by checking the `cX` and `cY` variables.

[image]

You can crop each individual ROI using Numpy slicing then save with `cv2.imwrite`

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours
ROI_number = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    # Obtain bounding rectangle to get measurements
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Find centroid
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    # Crop and save ROI
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    ROI_number += 1

    # Draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12), 4)
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 10, (320, 159, 22), -1) 

cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. Now I need to crop those images with the same size , I used numpy slicing but it gave an error like " **TypeError: string indices must be integers** " . how can I solve this or if there is any other method that I can use for cropping?

Comment: Check the update you can use Numpy slicing and save images with `cv2.imwrite`